# Does AJAX loading hurt search engine optimization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery, seo

I am building a blog for myself. Because it is relevant, here is the link: http://www.codetunnel.com. As you can see the page loads via AJAX so that I can do some stylish loading effects, among other things. It's actually a web-terminal that accepts commands and arguments and processes them via ajax; my URL structure executes these commands based on the URL passed in so that different pages can have unique URLs even though they are loaded via ajax. I've done past projects like this but have never cared much about optimizing the site for search engines, until this one.

Would a blog post being loaded via AJAX hurt its ability to be found by web crawlers? I'm assuming it would but I want your opinions before I decide how to move forward.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. If you use unobtrusive javascript and progressive enhancement meaning that in your page you have links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("foo bar", "foo")
```

which would be AJAXified in some external js file, web crawlers will follow those links as all normal links and if the server returns content this content will be indexed just as all other content of your site. But if the url is built with javascript, then, no, it won't be indexed as crawlers normally do not execute javascript. I would also recommend you providing a sitemap as well.

Comment: Gotcha, so ensuring the links work in a traditional manner first, then ajaxing them after the fact will still allow me to do some cool ajax loading and have web crawlers find the content. Got it.

Comment: @Chevex, absolutely, that's progressive enhancement. Just make sure your links provide indexable content if followed normally. Then you can have fun AJAXifying them.

Comment: Excellent answer. +1 Do you have any idea where I can do some reading on understanding this concept? Currently, on my ajax pages, I need to structure things in such a way where the initial ajax call is pre-loaded and any changes are loaded via ajax. What a pain.

Comment: Perfect. I'll have to do some major re-working of the site structure, but it will be worth it. Thank you.

Comment: @Dutchie432, here's a [nice article](http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/) worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes it would as from what I know the search engine wont see the loaded content, just the content from the initial page load.

Comment: That is what I thought. I just didn't know how much web crawlers have advanced. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use some kind of progressive enhancement (see [this](http://domscripting.com/presentations/xtech2006/) presentation), the main problem is that search engines will load and index only initial stuff.

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience in search engine optimization yes, it will hurt rankings of the website. But now Google has proposed a proposal through which you can use Ajax to load the pages and at the same time it won't hurt your SEO efforts.